# How to let users select the range of values of X1, X2... and Y in Multiple Regression using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, regression

```
Sub trail()

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$H$1:$H$" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) _
        , ActiveSheet.Range("$I$1:$L$" & Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), False, True, 95, ActiveSheet.Range( _
        "$V$2"), True, True, False, False, , False


End Sub
```

Here instead of Range from "H:H" and "I:L" i want to prompt the user to select the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an InputBox to prompt user for ranges and specify Type = 8 for range and then potentially use Linest

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetRegressionStatistics()
    Dim rX As Range, yRange As Range, vStat As Variant, xRange1 As Range, xRange2 As Range, xRange3 As Range

    Set xRange1 = [A2:A4] 'Application.InputBox("Please select x1 values", Type:=8)
    Set xRange2 = [B2:B4] 'Application.InputBox("Please select x2 values", Type:=8)
    Set xRange3 = [C2:C4] 'Application.InputBox("Please select x3 values", Type:=8)

    Set yRange = [D2:D4] ' Application.InputBox("Please select y values. The dimensions of y must match x", Type:=8)
    Set rX = Application.Union(xRange1, xRange2, xRange3)

    vStat = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yRange, rX, True, True)

    [F1].Resize(UBound(vStat, 1) + 1, UBound(vStat, 1) + 2) = vStat

End Sub
```

Above adapted from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/347468-multiple-linear-regression-vba.html).

[Linest info.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.linest)

Comment: the code lets me select the range but not outputting the regression output.

Comment: It outputs to V2 in the activesheet if you have selected ranges that match in length and width. I tested it. You may wish to change activesheet to an explicit sheet reference.

Comment: The Vba toolpack is active too.It prompt me to select the range ,i select the range from where my numbers are present and runs and output nothing.

Comment: Regression doesn't work on the file you sent too.i have approx 3 variables for my X variable.

Comment: The above is a gif of running my file. Are you running it as shown?

Comment: Yes running the same way.

Comment: I can’t think of any reason why running my file won’t generate the same output I’m afraid if you have the reference added.

Comment: What do you mean by reference?

Comment: Vba toolpak you would get an unknown error if you hadn’t added it

Comment: i check in programs files too,the file seems to be there.

Comment: Is there any other way i can do this ?

Comment: The above code works when there is single X but not with multiple X variable

Comment: Is the above ok using Linest?

Comment: I have tried that already. Linest is raw output so understanding the output would be difficult for people i am building this for.

Comment: The link I gave tells you what each index means. Simply loop the array and add in titles/descriptors. This is the way to do it as far as I can see. You don't need to write it all out in one go to sheet. You can very easily concantenate in the descriptors or have the descriptors already in the sheet and loop the array to place the values. You don't necessarily even need all the stats. It just required a few minutes leg work on your part.